# Having trouble with CSS background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a stock photo to cover my page. For some reason I cannot seem to get this to work. My image just refuses to cover the page.

```css
#cover {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE9pP.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #464646;
}

.cover-content {
  color: hsla(182, 100%, 28%, 1);
  font-family: font-family: 'Gravitas One', cursive;
  font-size: 400%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div class="cover-content">
    <h1>Snowfall Design Studio</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Minor point, but worth mentioning even though your question is already answered: `baclground-size: center center` is invalid and should either be removed, or changed to `background-position: center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page does not cover the whole viewport. If you want an image to cover the whole screen, put the background-image on the html or body element

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE9pP.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #464646;
}

.cover-content {
  color: hsla(182, 100%, 28%, 1);
  font-family: font-family: 'Gravitas One', cursive;
  font-size: 400%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div class="cover-content">
    <h1>Snowfall Design Studio</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `background-size: center center` is also invalid. May be a minor point, but worth mentioning I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the image covering the whole page: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owJVgq

You needed to move the background images to the body tag and add a viewport of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

---

If you are looking for this section to be just a section and have more content below the picture, this is what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZvbNe

Again you need to add the viewport, but also add:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```